# CSS rotated arrow has phantom-height

Tags: html, css, height, css-transforms

I have rotated an arrow, but it has phantom-height.

It also causes the hover effect to  launch, when I hover my mouse over the phantom height.

Image demonstration here:

[image: Phantom Height]

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #000000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
.dropdown {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.dropdown:hover {
    background-color: #00B3FF;
}
.dropdown-arrow {
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: please post your HTML and CSS code

Comment: please post your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the `display` as `block` and so the element would take 100% width. When it is rotated, the width becomes the height and hence you are seeing a large height.

The below snippet ***has a visual demonstration*** how the width of the element in default state becomes its height in the transformed state (just `hover` on the element).

```css
.dropdown-arrow {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s; /* just for demo */
  transform-origin: left bottom; /* just for demo */
}
.dropdown-arrow:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown-arrow'>></div>
```

---

Instead set the `display` as `inline-block`. Setting the display to inline-block means the element will not take 100% width and hence the *phantom height* will be avoided.

```css
.dropdown-arrow {
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown-arrow'>></div>
```

> **Note:** In both snippets, I have used only the code that is relevant to the question. The content of your `.dropdown-arrow` element might not be the same as what I've used but the behavior will be the same.

Comment: A nice game you created in the first snippet :)